# Javascript: Replace a string (a Russian special character) inside body

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace a string inside an affiliate page that I don't have direct access to the code but I'm allowed to add JS code. The page in question contains some errors that I want to fix. For example, I have this code:

```
<h2>Quotes DonвЂ™t Have to Be Complicated. We Make It Simple.</h2>
```

I want to replace "вЂ™" by "'" but it doesn't work with the code below, but when I use any other string it works. Am I missing something?

```
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("вЂ™", "'");
</script>
```

Thanks,

Comment: May be your string contain no single "вЂ™", try to use RegExp with g flag. str.replace(/вЂ™/g, "'");

Comment: Is that a valid code, because I tried it and it didn't work. I'm not ussed to Regex. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there are hidden whitespace characters, take a look at the source in hex editor.

Comment: @PavelGatnar no clue what you are talking about. But you are on something talking about HEX code,